# Firebase query not being fired

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I set breakpoints all throughout this query to Firebase, and all that's happening is the breakpoint for the following line gets hit (which is the very first line), and then no others.

```
_CHAT_REF.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

Any idea why this would be happening? Even if there is no data, the breakpoints inside the query block should be still be getting hit, but they aren't. What I've done: I've uninstalled and reinstalled Firebase at least 10 times, using both CocoaPods and not CocoaPods, following directions to the T. I'm not getting any kind of compile error, and I'm running FIRApp.configure() in my app delegate.

*Full Code (breakpoints on each line, none called only _CHAT_REF.observe line):*

```
private var _CHAT_REF = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("chats")

_CHAT_REF.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    self.individualMessages = []

    if snapshot.hasChildren() {
        // Found chats
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            let theChat = Chat(snapshot: snap as! FIRDataSnapshot)

            // The current user belongs to this chat, so add it to individual messages.
            if theChat.sender_id == GlobalEnv.currentUser.id || theChat.receiver_id == GlobalEnv.currentUser.id {
                self.individualMessages.append(theChat)
            }
        }
    } else {
        // No Children
        print("No children found.")
    }
    self.tvContacts.reloadData()
})
```

DB Structure:

[DB Structure on Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeWbF.png)

Comment: What does _CHAT_REF look like?

Comment: private var _CHAT_REF               = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("chats")

Comment: What does your DB structure look like?

Comment: Edited my original post with a link to the DB structure, thanks for the help.

Comment: I take it this code isn't also in `didFinishLaunching` with `FIRApp.configure`? Querying right away can cause problems on occasion

Comment: What happens when you print the snapshot?

Comment: No, this code is called later on in the app when they've already logged in (using MYSQL for login and most of the app). I'm essentially just using Firebase in this app to write/read messages without logging in through Firebase or authenticating in any way. I just noticed the rules were write != auth and read != auth and removed those, since that would have probably made sense if that was the issue. Still the same skipping though.

Comment: I can't print the snapshot because literally no line in between the first line and the closing brackets is getting called. I tried just adding in the print on the very first line with a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. It turned out that I wasn't able to read/write the database from behind my organization's proxy server. I built to a device using open wifi, and it worked.

Comment: I seem to be able to read/write from other apps just fine that I use Firebase with. It's just this one, an older Swift project I added Firebase to, that I'm having problems with. I also tried another device and wifi just now, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if it makes a difference. It's very simplified but the variable assignments are handled differently.

assume you are in a ViewController class...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    func clickAction() {  //just tied to an action in the UI
       let chatsRef = ref.child("chats")
       chatsRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
         print("Hello, World")
       })
    }
}
```